# Evince: How do I set a keybinding for the autoscroll?

Tags: lubuntu, pdf, evince, calibre

I use `evince` with `calibre` as my primary ebook reader on `Lubuntu 20.04`. I find the `autoscroll` feature pretty useful. How can I set a keybinding to toggle autoscroll on `evince`?